# uitableview delegate methods are not called

Tags: iphone, uitableview, delegates, methods

I've got the problem that tableview methods are not called the first time the tableview is shown.
If I switch back to the previous view, and then click the button to show the tableview again, the methods are called this time.

I should say that I show an actionsheet while the tableview is loading.
The actionsheet I call in the ViewWillAppear method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i fixed it by adding [self.tableView reloadData] after dismissing the actionsheet. i don't know if it's the proper way, but it somehow works.